# Performant way to dump DS18B20 data to Mongo

Tags: python, node.js, ds18b20, mongodb

I've worked with DS18B20 sensors before and have written and used scripts to access their data and make it available to a webserver using Flask and javascript. Now however I'm looking for a way to simply dump their data to a MongoDB collection. I've (finally) got Meteor installed (or rather an [ARM supporting fork of Meteor](https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor)), and if I could dump the data to a collection, then publish a subset of that data, realtime graphing would be possible.

Right now I'm thinking that a python script that executes on startup would be easiest. It would dump the sensor ID and reported temperature. I'm not sure what package to use to have a simple python script to connect to Mongo though and I'm not sure what the consequences of multiple connections to Mongo would be.

**Update** - here's an example gist
https://gist.github.com/archonic/8d2d936c8f25f3cb84004f01d58c135c

Comment: Where is mongo running (the Pi or another machine). Why not continuosly send the data to mongo. Mongo has great Python support using pymongo is very straightforward. If you are really interested in learning more mongo offers a course on using mongo from python https://university.mongodb.com/?_ga=1.163808317.324327173.1461545518 - which I casn personally recommend. I can also recommend this book http://www.amazon.com/MongoDB-Python-Patterns-processes-document-oriented/dp/1449310370/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1461545655&sr=8-1&keywords=mongodb+and+python.

Comment: Mongo would be running on the Pi. I'm familiar with the concept of sending data to Mongo, I'm more looking for the syntax to send all sensor data to a collection with the sensor ID and a timestamp. I would need the json library, and pymongo of course. I should have an example gist soon. This looks handy as well: https://github.com/timofurrer/w1thermsensor